# Bracket with multiple lines

Tags: brackets, text, cases, braces, inline

The errors of my codes with feedback: **Missing $ inserted**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\begin{document}

$[x_0: x_1: x_2]\mapsto$
    \begin{cases}
      $[x_0: x_1]$ & \text{ if } $x_1\neq 0$\\
      $[x_2: x_0]$ & \text{ if } $x_2\neq 0$
    \end{cases} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: `$...$` is for short bits of math inline. For displayed math, put everything inside `\[...\]` and don't use any `$` inside.  You may want to check out https://www.learnlatex.org/ to get a good tutorial on using LaTeX.

Comment: And either way, `cases` should be in math mode, not outside of it.

Comment: Thanks for all! Got it! Thanks for editing, btw

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP's issue was solved by a comment.

Comment: Note that, if you also load package `mathtools`, then you can use simply: `\[
[x_0: x_1: x_2]\mapsto
    \begin{cases*}
      [x_0: x_1] &if $x_1\neq 0$\\
      [x_2: x_0] &if $x_2\neq 0$
    \end{cases*} 
\]`